# WPF Datagrid with horizontal and vertical grid lines with centered target

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have created an empty grid with both horizontal and vertical lines but no data.  Centered within this grid I would like a plus sign cursor that can be moved with the arrow keys, I am not finding any good examples of doing this....

Here is my WPF code that I have so far but I am unclear how to add a **+** sign in the middle of this grid that I can move up/down/left/right.

Any advice is much appreciated as I am seeming to hit a roadblock here.

```
<Window x:Class="Crosshairs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
  <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Width="250" Height="250">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  </Grid>
  </Border>
  </Grid>
  </Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
  <Window x:Class="Crosshairs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
  <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" ShowGridLines="True" Width="250" Height="250" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="+" FontSize="24" Grid.Column="{Binding Position.X}" Grid.Row="{Binding Position.Y}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" Margin="-17,-20,0,-27" />
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

behind code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Position.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Up:
                if (this.Position.Y <= 0) { break; }
                this.Position = new Point(this.Position.X, this.Position.Y - 1); break;
            case Key.Down:
                if (this.Position.Y >= this.PART_Grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1) { break; }
                this.Position = new Point(this.Position.X, this.Position.Y + 1); break;
            case Key.Left:
                if (this.Position.X <= 0) { break; }
                this.Position = new Point(this.Position.X - 1, this.Position.Y); break;
            case Key.Right:
                if (this.Position.X >= this.PART_Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1) { break; }
                this.Position = new Point(this.Position.X + 1, this.Position.Y); break;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) 
    { 
        this.Position = new Point(8, 9); 
        // set the position 
        base.OnInitialized(e); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks promising but Visual Studio is complaining about this line: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=x:MainWindow}}"  The error is: the type converter for relativesource does not support converting from a string.  Any ideas?

Comment: --> This is what I figured out to get your sample working on my machine: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  Thanks A BUNCH!

Comment: any ideas on how I can get the + sign in the exact middle of the grid and have it move on the lines instead of between columns and rows?  I'd like to see it move on the x/y axis instead of appearing from box to box based on the direction of the arrows.

Comment: if you want to have marker(+) moved on the lines, you can use margin property. like this: <TextBlock Text="+" Grid.Column="{Binding Position.X}" Grid.Row="{Binding Position.Y}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" Margin="-10,-10,0,0"/> Of cause, this way is not good. Need to change from static values to dynamic values with Binding and ValueConverter.

Comment: For the margin, I used -22,-22,0,0 and this worked great but I am not sure what you mean by your last sentence.  Do you have an example?

Comment: If you use static values, you have to change the values when the situation or condition is changed.(ex. if width of grid is changed from 100 to 200, margin value have to be changed.)  So I pointed that you need to solve this problem.

Comment: I see, well this grid should remain fixed in size within the user's interface.  Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: One last question, is there a property that would allow me to set the starting position of the grid at the center {-22,-22,-250,-250} of the grid?  I would like to have the position move up, down, left and right from the center of the grid, instead of the upper left corner.

Comment: You can initialize the position. [behind code] 
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Position = new Point(6, 7); // set the position
        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }